# Evaluating performance of cascade classifier

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have my cascade classifier for object detection, trained using opencv_traincascade. 
How can I evaluate performance of this classifier?
Do I need some test images with objects that I want to detect, and some file with position of the objects on the image?

What criteria are best for measure object detection performance?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about every aspect of your question?

Comment: I want to calculate accuracy of my cascade. How to do this? All I have is my cascade.xml trained with opencv_traincascade.

Comment: @Artur have you find any solution to check your accuracy ??

Comment: @Whoosis I've used TPR and PPV ROC.